# Refresh DataSource using Spring+dbcp

Tags: java, spring, datasource, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm using Spring with DBCP and need to refresh my datasource when some configuration on operation environment changes, without restart all application.

If I do it with no use of DBCP, I force this refresh closing current opened datasource in use and Start a new instance of DataSource.

Using DBCP+Spring, I can't do that.

Somebody knows if it is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is such a support in plain DBCP, mostly because database connection properties are very rarely changing during the lifetime of the application. Also you will have to consider transition time, when some connections served by the old data source are still opened while others are already served from the new (refreshed) one.

#### Decorator/proxy approach

I would suggest you to write custom implementation of [DataSource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) leveraging Decorator/Proxy design pattern. Your implementation would simply call target data source (created by DBCP), most of the time doing nothing more. But when you call some sort of `refresh()` method, your decorator will close previously created data source and create new one with fresh configuration. Remember about multi-threading!

```
@Service
public class RefreshableDataSource implements DataSource {

    private AtomicReference<DataSource> target = new AtomicReference<DataSource>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void refresh() {
        target.set(createDsManuallyUsingSomeExternalConfigurationSource());
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return target.get().getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        return target.get().getConnection(username, password);
    }

    //Rest of DataSource methods

}
```

The `createDsManuallyUsingSomeExternalConfigurationSource()` method might look like this:

```
private DataSource createDsManuallyUsingSomeExternalConfigurationSource() {
    DataSource ds = new org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    ds.setUrl(/*New database URL*/);
    ds.setUsername(/*New username*/);
    ds.setPassword(/*New password*/);
    return ds;
}
```

This is a rough equivalent of Spring bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

You can't just inject such a target bean into your proxy/decorator `RefreshableDataSource` as you want data source configuration to be dynamic/refreshable, while Spring only allows you to inject static properties. This means that it is your responsibility to create an instance of target `BasicDataSource`, but as you can see, it is nothing scary.

Actually, I have a second thought: Spring [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) AFAIK allows you to call other beans' methods from XML configuration. But this is a very wide topic.

#### JNDI approach

Another approach might be to use JNDI to fetch `DataSource` and use hot-deployment (it works with JBoss and its `*-ds.xml` files.

Comment: +1 As this is what I would suggest as well. But you could take this a step further in Spring. You can inject your RefreshableDataSource as a singleton bean, being your only datasource within a run of your application. Then make a different DataSource bean marked as a prototype, so that each time you get it, you get a new one. The new one is what's injected into the RefreshableDataSource.

Comment: Thanks by supporting! My old implementation, based on manually instantiated datasource, this solution works. It's exactly my old strategy. But, now, I'm migration my manual mode to Spring dep. injection. When I tried to refresh the datasource, I don't know how to obtain a new spring bean reference to dbcp.BasicDataSource. Maybe, my question is wrong. To simplify, I can change it to: How to refresh a spring bean? With this answer, we can try to respond how to refresh the instance of BasicDataSource instantiated by Spring.

Comment: @rfeak: using prototype beans together with lookup-method is clever, but you still have to somehow instruct Spring about changed properties (they cannot be hardcoded)

Comment: @apast: I edited my answer, hope it helps you. I think using SpEL might simplify a bit, but first try manual approach.

Comment: Yes. To do this, the properties for the actual DB connection or pool must come from somewhere else. I've been able to do it with external properties files (for a different solution, but similar goal).